# Presenter is not called in onClick

Tags: android, android-databinding, presenter

When trying to inflate and set my presenter to my databinding component in this way my presenter methods are not called.

```
val fragmentBinding = FragmentListEditBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
fragmentBinding.presenter = ListEditorPresenter(this, requireContext())
```

but when using this

```
val fragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<FragmentListEditBinding(requireActivity(), R.layout.fragment_list_edit)    
fragmentBinding.presenter = ListEditorPresenter(this, requireContext())
```

It works fine, but then the layout is covering the full screen.
Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Please tell me if more context is needed.

Comment: Check out the answer and feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

The second method is for activity, not for the fragment, For fragment, you have to do it in the first method.

Before DataBinding and ViewBinding, In and `activity` we call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` to set the view for the `activity`, but for `fragment`, we override the `onCreateView` method and inflate a view and return it.

So the way of setting view for `activity` and `fragment` is different from the beginning.

So the `DataBindingUtil.setContentView` is made for activity, while the `FragmentListEditBinding.inflate` custom/manual inflation is made for fragment. As i have already mentioned it above.